Not saving total price for orders in drupal commerce
I tried to implement saving total price in orders but it`s returning an issue like before saving everything is good, but after it debug returning null
protected function createOrder($order_data) {
    $user = user_load_by_mail($order_data['Email']);
    if (!$user) {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $order_data['Customer'],
            'mail' => $order_data['Email'],
            'status' => 1,
        ]);
        $user->save();
    }

    // Get currency code and amount
    $splitAmount = $this->getCurrencyCode($order_data['Total']);
    $formatted_value = number_format((float) $splitAmount['value'], 6, '.', '');
    
    // Create the order
    $order = Order::create([
        'type' => 'default',
        'state' => $order_data['Status'],
        'uid' => $user->id(),
        'order_number' => $order_data['ID'],
        'mail' => $user->getEmail(),
        'placed' => strtotime($order_data['Date']),
        'overridden_unit_price' => TRUE,
    ]);

    // Create a Price object and set it to the order
    $amount = new Price($splitAmount['value'], $splitAmount['currency_code']);
    $order->set('total_price', $amount);
    dd($order->get('total_price')->getValue());
    $order->save();
    // $order = Order::load($order->id());

    // Debug the total price after saving
    dd($order->get('total_price')->getValue());
// Debug the total price to check the result
// dd($order->get('total_price')->getValue());
   
}

the first debug
 array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "number" => "1107000"
    "currency_code" => "LBP"
  ]
]

the second one
 []

I tried to debug and changed the data what comes to Price

Why you just use a temp var for this value? if you are using this value later in the render process

What a temp var?

Anton971 "temporary var" - short cut temp var or var

ok, I will check this var
